# How can I identify inconsistent column headings containing the same data within SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a DB and there are multiple tables that contain PKs and FKs but they are inconsistently named. For example containing the same data I have fields like: EmpID, Employee_ID, Eid, ect..

I see SQL Redgate has a data dictionary generating tool but I do not see in its functionality a way to aggregate all identical column data.

Comment: There would be no way to do this accurately. Your brain can see EmpID and Employee_ID an extrapolate that those are very likely the same thing. But there is no way to write code to do that. And forget something so vague as Eid. What you are asking for here is literally impossible. Even if you wrote some horrific kludge to "match" up columns you have no way to be certain that the matches are correct or that there aren't others you missed.

Comment: Also consider the anti-pattern that I see far too often where in the Employees table the primary key is ID. But in other tables it is EmpID or some variant of that.

Comment: Some tables may also have self-references and multiple references to a single table, e.g. table `Employees` may have `EmployeeId` for each employee and a reference to `ReportsToId` for their supervisor in the same table and perhaps an `AdministrativeAssistantId` for the employee that keeps them on the right track. Throw in `AddedById`, `UpdatedById` and a few others and it's quite a party. Some of the "referential integrity" might be implemented by triggers that do magic with history tables or allow curiosities like reusing a `Username` after an employee departs _sans_ unique constraint.

Comment: Thank you Sean Lange for commenting without giving any actual solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have FKs, so you can build a list off of that. You have to be aware that it will not necessarily be a **complete** list - it will only be a list of columns that have been defined in foreign keys. Outside of this your option is, as Sean mentioned a "horrific kludge" and would also not be guaranteed to have all of the matches. Logical column matches do not necessarily have to be named anything remotely similar and you could very well have an Employee_ID column in one table that matches something vague... like UrineSupplier (for example...)

But strictly for FKs relationships...

```
SELECT  obj.name AS FK_NAME,
    sch.name AS [schema_name],
    tab1.name AS [table],
    col1.name AS [column],
    tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
    col2.name AS [referenced_column]
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
WHERE col1.name <> col2.name
```

This code is almost entirely something I found and saved off at some point, so no credit to me. But I don't know the author either so there's that...